# Why a java interface returns itself <java.nio.file.Path>

Tags: java, interface

Why a java interface returns itself?

I'm reading the current code

```
public class Find {
public static class Finder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{
    private final PathMatcher matcher;
    private int numMatches = 0;

    Finder(String pattern){
        matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
    }

    void find(Path file){
        Path name = file.getFileName();
        System.out.println("Name " + name);
        if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)){
            numMatches++;
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }

    void done(){
        System.out.println("Matched: " + numMatches);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs){
        find(file);
        return CONTINUE;
    }
```

Looking at the file.getFileName(), it is represented by a interface

```
public interface Path
extends Comparable<Path>, Iterable<Path>, Watchable
```

But the returning value is as you can see in the line

```
System.out.println("Name " + name);
```

It must be a string because it is printable.

But looking at the interface

```
/**
 * Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this path as a
 * {@code Path} object. The file name is the <em>farthest</em> element from
 * the root in the directory hierarchy.
 *
 * @return  a path representing the name of the file or directory, or
 *          {@code null} if this path has zero elements
 */
Path getFileName();
```

it returns a Path object, why is acting in this way?

Comment: "It must be a string because it is printable." That doesn't follow. Every object in Java is printable, because of the toString() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` when used with a least one operand of type `String` is the `String` concatenation operator. You'll want to look into the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

The [Java tutorial on Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) states

> The + operator is widely used in print statements. For example:
>
> ```
> String string1 = "saw I was "; 
> System.out.println("Dot " + string1 + "Tod");
> ```
>
> which prints
>
> ```
> Dot saw I was Tod
> ```
>
> Such a concatenation can be a mixture of any
>   objects. For each object that is not a String, its toString() method
>   is called to convert it to a String.

Basically, all reference types inherit the `Object` class and therefore inherit the `toString()` method. When you concatenate a `String` and an reference of a different type, that type's `toString()` method is invoked and the resulting `String` is concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false:

> It must be a string because it is printable.

When using a variable in place of a `String` the Java compiler will implicitly call the object's `toString()` method (which all objects have).  For `Path` that will output a string representation of the path.  Just because something prints out text does not mean it's an actual `String` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Path getFileName() returns Path Object , so whenever we print object ,its toString() method will be called which is inherited from Object class.

so Path's toString() method is called and it returns path object in string form.

so do something like `path.getFileName().getName();` to get the name if there is such method.